# Using scraped data in Android

Tags: android-studio, push-notification, scrapy

I want to implement a notification system in Android studio.I have deployed my scrapy python project to https://scrapinghub.com and want my android app to check the data yielded by this scrapy project every 12 hours and thereby generate notifications based on this data.

Thanks!